# How to know if files inside an encrypted ZFS dataset are actually encrypted or not?

Tags: encryption, disk, zfs, data

When you make any change on a zfs dataset, changes are not applied to already existant data. So, if you find a ZFS dataset that says it has encyption ON, there is a way to check if an individual file has its data really encrypted or not?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I am not sure, if this is reliable, but it might give a hin in the prudent direction: query the key date versus the file modification date and compare the values.

```
#zfs get rekeydate <pool>/<dataset>
NAME              PROPERTY   VALUE                  SOURCE
<pool>/<dataset>  rekeydate  Tue Dec 15 15:43 2022  local
```

That would be the date of the last keychange - and should therefore match the first encryption if you never changed it before. Compare this against `stat file` (modification time).

Comment: Being ZFS a CoW FS, this not ensures you that the file contents are in fact fully encrypted, specifically it would be a problem for file sizes bigger than dataset recordsize. I suppose there is no real way to track all the chunks of a file and individually check if they have been encrypted or not.

Answer (score 1):

> When you make any change on a zfs dataset, changes are not applied to
> already existant data.

This is true for changeable properties like turning on compression or changing the compression method, but encryption can be activated only when the filesystem is created, and cannot be de-activated.  As such, encryption is never a "change" to the dataset.  It **has** to be enabled **before** the data is written to the dataset.

Therefore, one can be assured that any data written to an encrypted dataset is indeed encrypted.